# Change default input answer in Terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, default

While installing VMware Tools. After running command `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d` , it shows a message about the availability of open vm tools and asks if you still want to install vmware tools and automatically selects the input [no] then abort the installation. And states it's a default value. How would I able to change that answer to yes so I can install the vmware tools. Plus I'm a beginner so I can not understand complex terminologies.I have looked up everywhere. plz help. Here is the output

```
recommends using open-vm-tools packages. See http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803 for more information.
Do you still want to proceed with this installation? [no]
INPUT: [no] default
```

Comment: please show us the messages.

Comment: @pLumo I just did

Comment: @tatsu I cannot understand what's going on there. My probelm does not seem that complex. I just want to change default answer value to "yes"

Comment: default value comes from your install script, not the Terminal. You must type `y` or `yes` and then `Enter`. If you just press `Enter` it will take the default value which is no.

Comment: @QasimFerozeKhan if that is all open vmware-install.pl with your favorite editor and find the [no] and change it to [yes] (both the echo to screen and the actual passing of the answer)

Comment: Probably you run that command without VMware guest, try to use the feature VMware Workstation with choose `VM` menu and choose `install VMware Tools` as guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you still want to proceed with this installation? [no]

This asks for an answer to the question. If you press `Enter` at this point, the script will choose the default answer, which is shown in brackets. Sometimes it is written as `[YES/no]` or `[y/N]`, then the default value is the uppercase one.

To overrule the default, you simply have to type `yes` or most of the times `y` is enough, and then press `Enter` to proceed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Qasim wants a solution with only the [enter] keystroke, or nothing at all. Just tell him that's not possible.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that: "How would I able to change that answer to yes **so I can install the vmware tools**" ...

Comment: okay then it should be fine.

Comment: @pLumo thanks mate it worked with ```y``` but it didn't start installation anyway